# Managing data with realm and firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, realm

I have a simple question, and this might be the best place to ask it. I am building an Android app, and people say that is a good practice to have a lot of data local and not on the cloud, so I use realm and firebase to manage this, with realm I can have local data and firebase server data, so the user can access some data faster, like their own profile.

My doubt is can other users access this data? Which type of data should I manage with realm? Can I manage users class with realm and firebase? 2 different classes with same name where 1 extends RealmObject?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is good practice, BUT i wouldint worry bout it, especialy if it is some sort of social networking app. (atleast ur post gives me idea of it).

offline stored stuff should be: Information that rarely changes, like blog posts, or some sort of list application data, like list of "programming tips" or something

Comment: Without Caps can we talk at chat?

Comment: Just forget realmDB side for time beeing, and after you get more experience - implement it

Comment: well, i have just one problem, that i would like to avoid, i use firebase atm, and it takes some time to load data is there a way to increase performance?

Comment: A) better internet
B) less data
C) custom server (mySQL/mongoDB and php hybrid- with that you could specify exacly what data to send/receive. something like this https://github.com/WithoutCaps/PHPCommunication)